# Проскакивает getline при повторном вызове функции

Tags: c++, файлы, struct

Здравствуйте, делаю лабораторную по ООП(C++), цель: записать информацию про студента в файл используя структуры. Вот кусок кода где выполняется данная операция:

```
struct student
{
    string name;
    string address;
    string number;
};
string n, a, nu;
student KI[30];
void Addinfo(student* KI)
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Имя и фамилия студента" << endl;
    getline(cin, n);
    cout << "Домашний адресс студента" << endl;
    getline(cin, a);
    cout << "Телефонный номер студента" << endl;
    cin >> nu;
    KI[0].name = n;
    KI[0].address = a;
    KI[0].number = nu;
}
void AddStudent()
{
    ofstream infodat("INFO.txt", ios::app);

    if (infodat.fail())
        cerr << "Ошибка открытия файла INFO.txt" << endl;
    else
    {
        Addinfo(KI);
        infodat.write((char*) &KI[0], sizeof(student));
        infodat.close();
    }

    infodat.close();
    main();
}
```

Проблема в следующем: Когда я вызываю функцию 1 раз, всё работает хорошо, но при вызове функции 2 раз(не закрывая програму), програма проскакивает строчку:

```
cout << "Имя и фамилия студента" << endl;
                getline(cin, n);
```

И в консоли выходит это: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tb3IV.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Читайте все с помощью `getline`.
В этом случае `enter` тоже вычитывается из буфера.
Если читать через `cin >> nu`, то `enter` игнорируется и вычитывается при следующем запуске `getline`. И вы получаете пустую строку.

```
void Addinfo(student *KI)
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Имя и фамилия студента" << endl;
    getline(cin, n);
    cout << "Домашний адресс студента" << endl;
    getline(cin, a);
    cout << "Телефонный номер студента" << endl;
    getline(cin, nu);
    KI[0].name = n;
    KI[0].address = a;
    KI[0].number = nu;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Вопрос решен. Поставь галочку в одном из ответов.

Answer (score 0):

Сбрасывайте буфер. После `cin >> nu;` в нем остается `\n`, и при последующем чтении `getline` читается пустая строка.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь.